# import python packages in azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

i am trying to use our custom python package in azure function but it is saying modulenotfounderror

strcuture:

```
import azure.functions as func
from pythonpackage.featureimpl import  feature as f
```

but it showed me error Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonpackage'

where should i put these python packages so that it can be imported into azure funtion

Answer (score 0):

1. If **'pythonpackage''** is a `public module` that can be installed using pip, you should include it in the `requirements.txt` file.
   [Microsoft Documentation Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,azurecli-linux,application-level#folder-structure),
2. If **'pythonpackage''** is a `self-created module`, then it is a python relative import query. You must include in a folder and ensure that the folder is accessible.

```py
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  
sys.path.insert(0, dir_path)

import azure.functions as func  
from pythonpackage.featureimpl import feature as f
```

For further information refer these [Import custom modules in azure python-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318794/import-custom-modules-in-azure-python-function) and [Import module into python azure-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998307/import-module-into-python-azure-function).

Comment: sys path is working for only the top package there are sub packages in there which are not working