# How To use local python functions in Azure Functions App?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have trouble getting a function in Functions App to work when importing a local file.

My setup:

**function-app.py**

```
import azure.functions as func
#from . import test

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="* */5 *  * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def mytestfunc(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

**test.py**

```
print("testpy")
```

When the function is set up like this (note that line 2 is commented out) everything works as expected and I can see the function in Function Apps:

[image]

But as soon as I uncomment line 2 (activate the import) and publish to Function Apps the function disappears:

[image]

Is it not possible to import from local files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import custom modules in azure python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318794/import-custom-modules-in-azure-python-function)

Comment: @zero yes, thanks, that's the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: yes, it is the same link. To avoid the redundancy of same problems/questions, we as a community try to keep the duplicates to the minimum, so as not to confuse the fellow developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318794/import-custom-modules-in-azure-python-function).

```
import os, sys
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, dir_path)

import azure.functions as func
from test import testfunc
```